# Adding captions to simple slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I used a simple jquery slideshow I found online to get this:

### HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
 <img src="1.jpg" width="580" height="360">
 <img src="2.jpg" width="580" height="360">
 <img src="3.jpg" width="580" height="360">
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}

.fadein { position:relative; width:580px; height:360px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
.fadein img {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
  -o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
  -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
}
```

### JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('img').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      4000);
  });
```

I figured out how to add the box shadow to the images. I want to add semi-transparent captions to each image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

http://www.queness.com/post/152/simple-jquery-image-slide-show-with-semi-transparent-caption

Or the updated one

http://www.queness.com/post/1450/jquery-photo-slide-show-with-slick-caption-tutorial-revisited

Answer (score 0):

## A working Example for your code

[Example on Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tL3yF/)

## CSS

```
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}

.fadein { position:relative; width:580px; height:360px; }
.fadein div.slide { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:580px; height:360px;}
.fadein div.slide {
box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
-ms-box-shadow: 0 0 4px #666;
}
div.slide img {
position:absolute;  z-index:1;}
div.slide h2 {
position:absolute; top:20px; z-index:2; margin:0; padding:0; font-size:2em; background:rgba(32, 34, 38, .4); line-height:2.1em; font-weight:normal; color:#ffffff; margin-bottom:2px; clear:both; padding:1px 7px; float:none;
}
```

## Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $('.fadein .slide:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein .slide:first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('.slide').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    },
  4000);
});
```

## HTML

```
<div class="fadein">

    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.wallpaper4me.com/images/wallpapers/lifethroughdew-766931.jpeg" width="580" height="360" /><h2>The first Pic</h2></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT698nzLZwHByltzr9IoJNbTjyJ7mHeHPgBsJP159GdjAPHT22A" width="580" height="360" /><h2>Here is the Second photo </h2></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="http://www.gurucareersnetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Google-Tel-Aviv-Office-Flower-Pots.jpg" width="580" height="360" /><h2>last</h2></div>

</div>
```